# ODE solution with NDSolve, why do I get no value?

Tags: differential-equations

```
NDSolve[
  {x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == 15*(x[t]^2-t^2)*y[t]}, 
  {x[t] = 0.1, y[t] = 0.8}, 
  {t, -1, 0}]
```

Comment: Your initial conditions should be stated for a single time `x[0] == 0.1` etc. and use the double `==` which is `Equal`, not a single `=` which is `Set[]`.  Execute `Clear[x, y]` before retrying to clear your mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Quite a few problems here.

1. your [syntax for `NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) appears incorrect in more ways than one: you will want to look it up in the documentation.
2. you should use `==` (double equal) for equations, not `=` (which is used to set values instead); you will also need to `ClearAll[x,y]` before re-running your code;
3. your boundary conditions do not make sense: is e.g. x[t] really a
   constant and equal to 0.1? Did you mean `x[0] == 0.1` or something
   like that?

If you fix the syntax, and assign appropriate boundary values, you can at least get a solution:

```
NDSolve[
  {x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == 15*(x[t]^2 - t^2)*y[t], x[0] == 0.1, y[0] == 0.8}, 
  {x, y}, {t, -1, 0}
]

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. soln], {t, -1, 0}]
```

[image: solutions plot]

Whether this is the solution you were interested in will depend on your own choice of initial values.